# adding columns to datagrid and changing headers

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

I created a list of objects with specific properties and then I binded it to a dataGrid 
the order of the columns was not as I expected because I inherited properties from a base class and added other ones to the inheriting class so I tried changing the order manually but that didn't work.
So, my question is how to change the order and the headers of the columns when a list is binded to a datagrid. here's an example that demonstrates what Iam trying to accomplish :

```
    class Program
{
    void showData()
    {
        test2 t1 = new test2() { p1 = 1, p2 = 6, p3 = 9 };
        test2 t2 = new test2() { p1 = 4, p2 = 5, p3 = 6 };
        List<test2> l = new List<test2>();
        l.Add(t1);
        l.Add(t2);
        datagrid1.ItemsSource = l; // p3 appears in the first column of the grid but I want it to be in the last column
    }
}
class test
{
    public int p1 { get; set; }
    public int p2 { get; set; }
}
class test2 : test
{
    public int p3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't auto generate the columns

Comment: sorry I didn't fully get the idea but do you mean that I have to make columns before binding the list to the datagrid? thanks,

Comment: Yes see the posted answer.  If you want to control the columns then don't auto generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the columns manually in the XAML part of your control:

```
    <DataGrid Name="datagrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="p1" Binding="{Binding p1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="p2" Binding="{Binding p2}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="p3" Binding="{Binding p3}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I got duplicated data the columns are made twice.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the AutoGenerateColumns attribute. I have updated my answer.